# ios5 UISearchBar to filter tableview causes Assertion error with a null cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, uisearchbar

I'm using ios5 storyboard and have a tablview with a uisearchbar that I'm using the filter the results. I'm following the tip from the following blog post where I also posed this question 
http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/01/08/ios-quick-tip-filtering-a-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/:

The problem I see is that when getting back items from my filtered array the custom UITableViewCell comes back as null. In iOS5 I understand you should only have to get a cell via dequieReusableCell and not explicitily init a cell. However when the search in the search bar successfully matches the cell comes back as null. I’m not sure how I can manually init my cell with the custom style. Any ideas?
Here’s a snippet from my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

ItemCell *cell = (ItemCell *)[tableView
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
self.searchBar.tableView.
if (cell == nil){
NSLog(@”Why is this happening when I get a successfull match from the search bar?”);
}

This causes the following error :
Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘NSInternalInconsistencyException’, reason: ‘UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:’

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` on the wrong table.

Your prototypes are defined in your primary table, and need to be dequeued from there. When performing a search, you're being asked to fill out a special search table. That table doesn't contain your cell prototypes, and it doesn't search the original table for the prototypes!

Your table is still available as `self.tableView`. And you can dequeue from there, even for the search results table.

Instead of this:

```
ItemCell *cell = (ItemCell *)[tableView
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Use this:

```
ItemCell *cell = (ItemCell *)[self.tableView
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```